# ASP.NET 5 Mac Development Creating a Solution .NET Generator?

Tags: c#, dnx

So I am curious I have followed:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/getting-started-with-asp-net-5-and-visual-studio-code-on-a-mac.html
Its pretty straight forward on building a console application.

I want to build a multi-tier class library project. I am unsure how to do this properly. I know a project.json is created when I create a class library project. But what if I want a Solution that contains many projects? How does that work in Mac development and translate over to Visual Studio on windows?

My idea is a project like solution like so:

```
MainProjectFolder
 -> tests (folder) 
 -> global.json
 -> src (folder)
    -> project1 (folder)
       -> project.json
    -> project2 (folder)
       -> project.json
```

How would you create a solution so I can store those files? Is this just currently not available? Do I just need to create an empty solution in Visual Studio then import those folders/projects?